# Python script that gets images from a webpage throwing error: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a script that is supposed to copy all image files from a website and then write them to a certain file in the directory. Code goes as follows:

```
 import urllib2
 import re
 from os.path import basename
 from urlparse import urlsplit

 url ='https://www.google.com'
 response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 source = response.read

 file = open("google.txt", "w")
 #.seek(0) is for the search
 file.seek(0)
 file.write(source)
 file.close()

 patten = '(http)?s?:?(\/\/[^"]*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg))'
 for line in open('google.txt'):
     for m in re.findall(pattern, line):
         filename = basename(urlsplit(m[1])[2])
         try:
             img = urllib2.urlopen('https:' + m[1]).read()
             file = open(filename, "w")
             file.write(img)
             file.close()
         except:
             pass
         break
```

The problem is that when it is executed, it throws `expected a character buffer object` on the line that contains `file.write(source)`.

I tried putting in `file.seek(0)` before the `file.write(source)` because I read online that it usually fixes the issue, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Change to the following: `source = response.read()` <- the `()` will execute the method for a response. You are currently trying to _write the method to the file_.

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to fix it.